# Checkbox binding in Knockout with array

Tags: arrays, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a question about knock out, here is my code in HTML and Javascript, can you tell me what is wrong with my code, when I click on check box the related isWaived in not checked

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isWaived(0)">
<div data-bind="visible: isWaived(0)" >
    <div class="alert">
        You have waived coverage for this member0.
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my javascript code

```
    function Member(idx, isWaived) {
        var self = this;
        self.idx = idx;
         self.isWaived = ko.observable(isWaived);

    }

    function ReviewCartViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        // Editable data


        self.members = ko.observableArray([
            new Member(0, true),
            new Member(1, false),
            new Member(2, false),
            new Member(3, false),
        ]);

        self.isWaived = function (idx) {
            for (var i in self.members()) {
                var member = self.members()[i];
                if (member.idx == idx)
                    return member.isWaived();
            }
        };

        self.DoWave = function (idxs) {
            for (var i in self.members()) {
                var member = self.members()[i];
                if (member.idx == idxs) {
                    member.isWaived(!member.isWaived());
                    //Send Ajax Request to waived the user
                }
            }
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ReviewCartViewModel());
```

here is the fiddle page of this script
http://jsfiddle.net/mohsenvafa/spMvd/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your binding (the `checked` binding on the radio button and the `visible` button on the div) with this:

```
members()[0].isWaived
```

The problem was that while Knockout can *read* from the value `isWaived(0)`, it cannot *write* to that value because it's the result of evaluating a function--it's not an observable. The observable we want here is the `isWaived` property of the `Member`, and the syntax above is how you hand it to Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is perhaps a little overengineered. With the correct bindings, you can remove both the isWaived  and DoWave functions from your root model. [Here is a jsfiddle of a working solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/spMvd/1/)

HTML

```
<!-- ko with:members()[0] -->
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:isWaived" />
</div>        
<div data-bind="visible:isWaived">
    <div class="alert">
        You have waived coverage for this member <span data-bind="text:idx"></span>.
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

Javascript

```
function Member(idx, isWaived) {
    var self = this;
    self.idx = idx;
    self.isWaived = ko.observable(isWaived);    
}

function ReviewCartViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // Editable data   

    self.members = ko.observableArray([
        new Member(0, true),
        new Member(1, false),
        new Member(2, false),
        new Member(3, false),
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReviewCartViewModel());
```